# A simple question about facebook comments plugin

Tags: facebook, graph, comments

I'm struggling with a very simple problem. The facebook documentation, as always, didn't give me enough explanation.

I attached a facebook comments plugin to my site. And using a callback of "comment.create" event, I can get information of a just-create comment.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

The json reponse looks like:

```
{"href":"http://siteaddress.com/page.htm", "commentID":"111122223333" }
```

What I like to do now is to retrieve the data of the single comment with the commentID. Although I expected that the following way should work:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/111122223333
```

it just gave me "False". I can retrieve all comments attached to that page using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids=http://siteaddress.com/page.htm
```

But, what is the right way to retrieve the single comment data just created using the commentID?

Comment: Please just edit your question to provide additional information.

Answer (score 9):

I was also facing the same problem... so what i did was , I queried the last posted comment or reply from the fb comments table using fql. Here I sort the comments by time in descending order and pick the top one. though one may think that if two comments are posted at same time, it may cause ambiguity, But in my case i tried and tested it invoving more than 2 users but i always got the expected result.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
    FB.api({
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: "select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='URL_OF_THE_COMMENT_BOX') or object_id in (select post_fbid from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='URL_OF_THE_COMMENT_BOX')) order by time desc limit 1"
      },
      function(response) {
        var feed = response[0];
        alert(feed.text)
      }
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are having comment id then why you dont use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) and query to [Comment Table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) to get all comment related data?

Comment: Thanks, Awais. Is it the only way to retrieve comment data using commentID? The document says that querying with post_fbuid (commentID returned on 'comment.create') is impossible since it has no index on it. Can you please show me an example of FQL using the commentID?

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same problem.  What seems to be happening is that the commentID and parentCommentID are actually just returning the unique ID of that page, and not a unique ID for the comment itself.

The unique ID for an individual comment is the unique ID of the page (that is, the value currently being returned as "commentID") with an underscore followed by another number (8 digits long in the tests I've done).  You can look this up directly from the graph the response provided it.

I have logged a bug with Facebook to hopefully get this fixed!  Bug at address below:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16535

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Darren.

It seems that there is no easy way to retrieve and save your comment using FB.event.subscribe().

BTW, i found an blog post which explains comment synching issue:

[link]http://www.loadedguntheory.com/blog/listpost/tim/Syncing_Comments_with_Facebook.html[/link]

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I can retreive comment data by id (id format like this: 1234567890123456_12345678). Ids i retreive from url like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids={$url}

Answer (score 0):

I combined a couple approaches (including from Charsee).

// this query takes a "commentID" and "href".  The commentID is returned on comment.create "response" object

// this code requires an escape function "addslashes(str)" to handle single quotes.

var query = "SELECT text, fromid FROM comment WHERE post_fbid='"+addslashes(commentID)+"' AND ( object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='"+addslashes(href)+"') or object_id in (select post_fbid from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='"+addslashes(href)+"')))";